# Execute JavaScript function from RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, validation

I have a asp.net textbox that uses a RegularExpressionValidator. If the regular expression fails, is it possible to execute a small client side javascript function to do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use customvalidator instead and then make it call a js function. In that function you can perform regular expression validation and what ever else you desire.